# Feels like a promotion attempt - is it spam?

Tags: discussion, spam-handling

I was doing Late Answers review when I bumped into this question:

[How do I export saved passwords from my firefox password manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403676/how-do-i-export-saved-passwords-from-my-firefox-password-manager)

The new user basically repeated a previously posted answer. They used a longer URL that ultimately leads to the same website and added another link that points to a web page that was created today. It actually covers the topic (it explains how the add-on work step-by-step), but I kind of feel like it's just posted to promote their website and not to improve AskUbuntu.

Should you flag such attempts as spam?

Comment: Yes, it would be considered advertisement which is a form of spam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mitch already deleted the post as spam.  I think it's safe to consider these types of things spam, because it's basically just advertising a site, and not adding to the answer at all.